# Validate before attr_writer is performed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have the following validations for my passwords:

```
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}, confirmation: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: :password_changed?
```

And I also have `attr_writer` to hash the password & password confirmation:

```
def password=(val)
  self[:password] = my_hash_func(value.to_s)
end
```

My problem is that when I create a new user, if that password is empty, or has less than 5 chars, when it hits the `attr_writer` it creates a value (even though it should not be valid).

What is the proper approach to avoid your attr_writers to bypass validation?

Comment: The result of a hash function is seldom the same length as the input. So validating the result as a minumum length of 5 doesn't make sense. You can have a second variable (e.g. `new_password`) store the unhashed version and validate that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `attr_writer` is called before validations takes place and your `my_hash_func` probably hashed empty password to some value which is of greater length than 5. You could have `hash_password` function, which would be called before model is saved.

```
class SomeClass
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }, confirmation: true, if: :password_changed?
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: :password_changed?

  before_save :hash_password, if: :password_changed?

  protected

  def hash_password
    self.password = my_hash_func(password)
  end 
end
```

You need `:password_changed?` checks because you only want to validate and hash password if it has been changed.